# Zend Framework 2: create sidebar

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to understand how is possible to generate the code for sidebar with diefferent content per module.

This is my layout.phtml (module/Application/view/layout)

```
....
<div class="main-container">
    <aside>
      <?php echo $this->sidebar; ?> 
    </aside>
    <section>
    <?php echo $this->content; ?>
    </section>
</div>
....
```

With my very little experience i can guess that $this->content is the output of the selected module, so how can i create a $this->sidebar per module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. Well, that's a little mean, so let me give you some explanation.

With Zend Framework 2 the use of `ViewHelpers` is highly encouraged. Creating a ViewHelper is very simple. The task of a ViewHelper should be as simple! Meaning, that whenever you create a ViewHelper it should have one very simple task, to give an example "Display the UserName of the currently logged in User".

In your case you want a "Sidebar". While this in itself is a very valid concern, you should rething about it: What is a Sidebar? A sidebar is a collection of widgets. A Widget is a ViewHelper! So your Sidebar would be a Collection of ViewHelpers!

**Approach 1 - suggested**

Create many dedicated ViewHelpers and then display your sidebar like this in your layout.phtml

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <h2>My Account</h2>
    <div class="widget_content">
        <?php echo $this->userMiniProfile();?>
    </div>
    <h2>My Calendar</h2>
    <div class="widget_content">
        <?php echo $this->userCalendar();?>
    </div>
    <h2>My Foo</h2>
    <div class="widget_content">
        <?php echo $this->bar();?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Approach 2** - only needed when you have dynamic sidebars

Create a ViewHelper called `sidebar` and display it like this:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <?php echo $this->sidebar();?>
</div>
```

With this setup, your viewHelper would then have some dependencies that check for the currently logged in user, load the sidebar form the database and then render the different widgets based on the services result.

**The Basics**

To create a simple ViewHelper, please see [this link sponsored by Evan Coury](http://blog.evan.pro/creating-a-simple-view-helper-in-zend-framework-2) or [a deeper introduction sponsored by Michael Gallego](http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2012/10/06/how-to-replace-the-action-helper-in-zf-2-and-make-great-widgetized-content/)